# Regex to match only the first occurrence on the string in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

When analyzing the logs you often need to find all lines containing some specific word in the log file. The problem is when you do a regular search in notepad++ it returns the same line multiple times, if it contains this word in different positions. To alleviate that I switch to regex search and use the following expression

```
(.*\K)(text)
```

Where `.*` matches the full line, `\K` discards the selection and then (text) matches the last occurrence of text on the line.
This method looks ugly and is not very fast. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To match only the first occurrence you will have to search `many` characters from beginning of line, discard that search and look for `text` that you are looking for.

Following regex does the same.

**Regex:** `(^.*?)\Ktrue` `true` is my text here.

**Dummy Input**

```
Log date 12/12/2015
Sr No      desc    amount     status
1          true    $10000     true
2          true    $10000     false
3          true    $10000     true
4          true    $10000     false
5          true    $10000     true
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZ3gN2/1)**

**Notepad++ Demo**

**[image: Notepad++ Demo]**

Comment: Very interesting way to explaining, how this attached Gif is created? any special tool?

Comment: This is a great answer!