# Extract the last word from the first line

Tags: regex

I want to capture the last word from the first line only not including the subsequent lines. I have the pattern below but it captures all the last words from all lines…

Here’s my pattern: https://regex101.com/r/pgU14C/1

```
Data:
*A* abcd efgh ijkl         Word
djdjfjfjfjfjfkfkfkfk       agjfj
gjfjfjfjfkfkffk            sjfjfj

Desired Match: Word
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the `global` flag and u will get ur desired output:

```
/\w+$/m
```

Comment: Hi @Henryc17,  when I use mark in notepad++ it captures all the last words.

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539883/regex-to-match-only-the-first-occurrence-on-the-string-in-notepad

Comment: The "Desired Match: 123abc" you wrote doesn't seem to make any sense. Could you check your question? Also, @Henryc17 's answer seems correct to me.

Comment: Hi @Odd One Out, sorry the match should have been word not 123abc.